# jQuery: Why does my click event on a li element not work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, html-lists

I want to move the Div-element "nav", when a li-element was clicked.

I have a List in a div

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#t1">Flyer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t2">Code</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t3">Angebot</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t4">Bilder</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Why doesnt this work in jquery:

```
$("#nav ul li").click(function(){
    $("#nav").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "-300px",
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: It works just as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/zet2d/1/

Comment: so... this should work.. whats wrong with it??

Comment: Your code is working fine (link)[http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/eY2yF/]

Comment: Where do you add your javascript code? Before or after the `<div id="nav">` ?

Comment: @user2477311 Did you add jquery refrence? Check the error console

Comment: Don't forget to add your code into `$(docuement).ready(function(){/* your code */})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code works fine as you expect, view the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zet2d/1).

I have a feeling your forgetting something like putting it in the jQuery DOM Ready event.

Make sure you code looks like this (inside the DOM Ready)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // When the DOM is Ready, then bind the click
    $("#nav ul li").click(function(){
        $("#nav").animate({ 
            marginLeft: "-300px",
        }, 1000 );
    });
});
```

Make sure you have no other javascript errors on your page (If you do before this code, the code will not work), Check your console (In chrome right click > Inspect Element > console).

One of these 2 issues are causing your problems (most likely), else you will have to debug it yourself (or show us more code).

Comment: YES MAN! Forget the ready function....thats a really bad mistake! THANKS FOR ALL THESE ANSWERS...but it only was the simpliest thing in the world :-)

Answer (score 12):

Depending on what version of Jquery you are using this may or may not work:

```
$('body').on('click', '#nav ul li', function(){
    $("#nav").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "-300px",
    }, 1000 );
});
```

I did $('body') because if you are generating these li's dynamically then you need to bind 'delegated events' as they're called.

Comment: Hero ! +1 for the dynamic knowledge .

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected, but you have to click on the li-element. If you click on the anchor, it might break on some browsers.

Here is a better approach on this.

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#t1">Flyer</a></li>
 <li><a href="#t2">Code</a></li>
 <li><a href="#t3">Angebot</a></li>
 <li><a href="#t4">Bilder</a></li>
 </ul></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {
    var nav = $('#nav');

    nav.find('a').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        nav.animate({ 
            marginLeft: "-300px",
        }, 1000 );
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And of course, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dKPqJ/

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one, and i think there is no error in your code as well.

in my knowledge your code will work if you give **float:left** property for **#nav**.

if you set **position** then the following code will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#nav ul li").click(function()
 {
    $("#nav").animate({ 
     left: "-=300px",
    }, 1000 );
 });
});
```

Or try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#nav ul li").click(function()
 {
   $("#nav").animate({
       "left": "-=300px"
    },
  "slow");
 });
});
```